# QGIS modeler: select by attribute wrong results

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, qgis-modeler, extract

I am new to QGIS modeler and trying to write a script in which certain attributes are selected and written to a shapefile. See the attached image for the script and the select by attributes box.

In the final shapefile there are still values <1 available.

What am I doing wrong.

[image: Modeler image]

Comment: Hard to say. Could you give the settings in the other tools/steps?

Comment: As @Miron suggested, the tool before _Select by attributes_ which you have called **Calculate Snelheid** is likely to be the culprit. Could you add a screenshot for the options used?

Comment: Solved it by writing the output to a PostGIS DB instead of a shapefile. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hm, still strange that the results were wrong using Sextante and the "select by attribute"...

Answer (score 5):

I have been facing the same issue some time ago. For me, its not the 'Select by attribute' algorithm, but the 'Extract by attribute', that delivers the desired result. I think the reason is, that 'Select by attribute' only creates a selection in QGIS, but does not return any data. 'Extract by attribute' creates a new dataset, which can be used for further processing in the modeler.

Here comes a screeshot illustrating the difference:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, you are correct in that the *Select by attribute* algorithm does not have an output but you **can still select** it as an input for further processing. But good catch on suggesting the *Extract by attribute* tool, +1!