# Select by location is not working in the processing modeler

Tags: qgis, select-by-location, qgis-modeler

When I run the modeler in qgis 2.14 I get no results from the select by location algorithm.  I tried outputting my buffer polygon and using the select by location plugin and it worked fine.  I have the same setting in both but for some reason the modeler doesn't do anything.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trial and error I found that adding all the parent algorithms makes the select by location work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Select by location` generates a selection on the input layer, and not a processible output layer. You may either...

- use `Extract by location` instead or
- use `Save selected features` with your `Select by location` result as input (screenshot).

[image]

cp. [QGIS modeler: select by attribute wrong results](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183043/qgis-modeler-select-by-attribute-wrong-results/187444#187444), same issue with `select by attribute`

Comment: I tried extract by location but it still gave me no results.  What I did find was if you add the parent algorithms the select by location does work.  Documentation on this stuff would sure help in the long run.