# Extract by location not working in qgis modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, extract

I am trying to extract lines to a new layer that don't fall 100% within a polygon.  I want to leave out anything that does. I can not get extract by location to work in the modeler, it does work when run by itself.  Is there another option or some information on how the plugin works.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with Extract by location when you select predicate 'crosses'? This gives me all linestrings of wich less than 100% fall into the polygon. Or do you want linestrings that are totally outside the polygon too? And didn't we just discuss Select by location in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256981/select-by-location-is-not-working-in-the-processing-modeler? I thought this works in modeller when setting parent algorithm?

Comment: The parent algorithm isn't working for extract by location.  This is a different project.  It does work outside the modeler but for some reason I can't get the model to produce a result.  I've added an image of the model as it currently stands.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It is the parent algorithm but only specific ones. Why isn't there better or complete documentation on using the native plugins? It eats a lot of time having to do trial and error or waiting for an answer on stack exchange just to get something to work.